# Lenovo S1 Yoga Lid Switch Disables Keybord and Trackpad

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, touchpad, lenovo, lid

Just installed LTS 20.04 on my Lenovo S1 Yoga. I have found though that the keyboard and mouse suspend when in laptop mode, and activate when in tablet mode.

Is there a way to reverse the effect of the lid switch in the config?

Thank you!

Comment: Note: this seems to be related, but is the reverse of the issue that I have.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/774949/how-to-disable-and-enable-keyboard-on-lenovo-yoga

Answer (score 0):

Completely shutting down, and closing the lid seems to have reset the lid switch.

I am sure there is a better more complete solution to fix this, but for now, this is working for me.